# How to get a navbar to display text depending on button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, navbar

I've been asked to try and replicate a page (they own the page) which is built in .php and recreate it into an editable page in .html and .css for use in Concrete, but I am facing some issues with getting the navbar to function correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/TYhnb/819/

It should only display the content under the appropriate tab by altering the contents display: function from 'none' to 'block' and vice versa whilst altering its class. I am 90% sure that this is going to be impossible to solve with css and html alone so does anyone have any advice on how I would go about implementing this?

CSS, HTML is on the fiddle

---

```
.tabs #tab-container-1-nav li.activeli a {
background: #1f5497;
color: #fff;
}

.tabs #tab-container-1-nav li a {
padding: 10px 15px;
background: #f2f2f2;
color: #4D4D4D;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}

.tabs #tab-container-1-nav li {
float: left;
display: inline;
margin-right: 8px;
}

.tabs ul {
list-style: none;
}

.main ul {
list-style: inside;
}

.main ul li {
font-size: 13px;
margin: 5px 0;
color: #0d3161;
}

div#tab-container-1 {
margin-top: 57px;
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript we can see? For direction, you'll want to add a click listener to each of your tabs to get which button was clicked with event.getSource()

Comment: What do you want to do ? Hide or show content when click on tabs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can do this with just HTML and CSS...using labels to check alternate radio input elements, the checked state of which is then use to determine the adjacent div elements display.

**See the second example below for tab highlighting on click...**

### [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TYhnb/820/)

HTML

```
<label for='tab1Content'>Tab 1</label>
<label for='tab2Content'>Tab 2</label>
<label for='tab3Content'>Tab 3</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type='radio' name='content' id='tab1Content' checked='true' />
<div>Tab 1 content</div>
<input type='radio' name='content' id='tab2Content' />
<div>Tab 2 content</div>
<input type='radio' name='content' id='tab3Content' />
<div>Tab 3 content</div>
```

CSS

```
label {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}
input[name=content] {
    display:none;
}
input[name=content] +div {
    display:none;
}
input[name=content]:checked +div {
    display:block;
}
```

---

With some more HTML and CSS trickery you can extend this to not only show content on click, but also highlight the currently selected tab...

### [Example 2: More complex - with tab selection](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TYhnb/825/)

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div>
        <input type='radio' name='content' id='tab1Content' checked='true' />
        <label for='tab1Content'>Tab 1</label>
        <div>Tab 1 content</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type='radio' name='content' id='tab2Content' />
        <label for='tab2Content'>Tab 2</label>
        <div>Tab 2 content</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type='radio' name='content' id='tab3Content' />
        <label for='tab3Content'>Tab 3</label>
        <div>Tab 3 content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
label {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
#wrapper > div {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
input[name=content] {
    display:none;
}
input[name=content]~div {
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:0;
}
input[name=content]:checked~div {
    display:block;
}
input[name=content]:checked~label {
    background:lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, straight forward answer and it is exactly the solution I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: One quick question, how would I go about changing the styling for the checked radio input element?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using CSS3, a quick google search showed me [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/), which houses a few demos (look towards the end for the link to the demo page).

If you need backward browser support, then perhaps use jQuery or some javascript library that provides this functionality. I have had much luck with [jqueryUI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript and import jQuery and jQuery UI in your project, then a simple way to do this is to use jQuery UI

**demo with your fiddle** :

http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/GT926/1/

demo on jquery UI
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Comment: Good solution and it does work but ideally I would like to avoid JavaScript where possible as it is painful adding it into the cms they are using.